# Google Sheet how to extract a column matching with another column?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I got for exemple my column number 1 and 2 on a sheet, column 1 is names and column 2 is their id's, I would like to extract that column 1 and 2 to another sheet (On the same global sheet just another sheet page inside it) with the same data matching, for exemple I got my column 1 already extracted with

```
=unique('Data1'!D2:$D)
```

Which just gives me the whole column, now I would like to extract my column 2 matching with the column 1, for exemple :

In line 18 for column 1 in the original sheet I got name : James
In line 18 for column 2 in the original sheet I got ID : 18

On my second sheet where i'm extracting data I got for exemple :

In line 7 for column 1 in the second sheet I got name : James

I would like to do so in column 2 in the second sheete I get the ID matching to the column 1 with the name.

I hope it's a clear question and hope someone can help me with it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try simple `VLOOKUP`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(D1:D, A:B, 2, 0)))
```

Comment: Just a last question, if my ID's aren't next to my NAME column, what can I use ? @player0

Comment: something like: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(D1:D, {Sheet1!A:A, Sheet1!X:X}, 2, 0)))`

Comment: Hey sorry for the disturb again, i've sent you a mail regarding another problem.